# A way to store div id as string and send it to button click event via javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Is there a way I can send my div id to my asp delete button?

```
div.ID = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return clickTheButton();");

    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //serverside code if confirm was pressed.
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM WallPosting WHERE idWallPosting = " + id + ")", cn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        //        //PopulateWallPosts();
    }
}
```

ASP:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_delete()
{
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this comment?");
}
function clickTheButton() {
    document.getElementById('<%= btn.ClientID %>').click();
}

</script>
<p>
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="return confirm_delete();" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" runat="server" Text="delete"/>
```

I need to find a way I can send the div id to the button delete so I can use my sql syntax, atm I cant see a way of how to send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use **window.event.srcElement.id** like this:

function clickTheButton() {

```
var Sender = window.event.srcElement;
alert("the item clicked was " + Sender.id)
```

}

for a button that looks like:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="clickTheButton();" value="Click Me"/>
```

you will get an alert that reads: "the item clicked was myButton.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a situation where you have a number of "delete" buttons, e.g. one for each comment, all hooked up to the same `btnDelete_Click()` event handler?

You can put a `CommandArgument` on the Button, e.g.:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="return confirm_delete();" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" runat="server" Text="delete" CommandArgument="123" />
```

And then pick this up in the event handler like so:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to change your ASP button to a HTML button.  Wire up an onclick event to the HTML button, and then call javascript function that then hits the server side Web Method.

You may want to re-approach your design, why is the div being selected causing a delete action.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the reference to the actual element, not just its id, you can define your div as:

```
<div id="myDiv" onClick="btnClickHandler(this)">
    ...
</div>
```

This will pass the actual div element into your javascript function `btnClickHandler`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnClickHandler(myDiv)
    {
        // do stuff with the div here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the divs id is set to something from my database and they are all dynamic

Comment: Is it the onclick of the div or a button that we're interested in? Are you using a div to simulate a button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494609/javascript-wont-do-a-postback-from-c-code-in-asp-net