# Javascript wont do a postback from c# code in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Ok managed to get the code working, as in no errors but it wont do a post back after ive confirmed when I click on the div?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_delete(id){
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
            __doPostBack('DivClicked', id);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class UserProfileWall : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //It is a postback so check if it was by div click (NOT WORKING because the javascript isnt posting back)
            string target = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
            if (target == "DivClicked")
            {
                string id = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
                //Call my delete function passing record id
                Response.Write(String.Format(id)); //just a test 
            }
        }
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
    }
    private void PopulateWallPosts(string userId)
    {

        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT idWallPosting, wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN User u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE wp.UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
            {
                //("SELECT wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    test1.Controls.Clear();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        div.Attributes["class"] = "test";


                        div.ID = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                        string id = Convert.ToString(div.ID);
                        //store the div id as a string
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
                        img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                        div.Controls.Add(img);
                        div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;" + "{0}", reader.GetString(1))));
                        div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete(" + id + ");");
                        // send the div id to javascript
                        div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                        test1.Controls.Add(div);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "')", cn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
    }
}
```

Any Reason why the code isnt executing a postback?

Comment: Are you sure the confirm function is returning true?

Comment: doesnt make a difference

Comment: By "this code isn't executing a postback" you mean "there is a post but  Page.IsPostBack is false"?

Comment: well what i mean is nothing happens, i click ok and no response is fired (page load) and like normal postback i get a page reload

Comment: If you get a page reload, then you can't say nothing happens. Something is happening, the page is reloading. The Page_Load event not getting raised correctly is different than the page not posting back. So is the page reloading?

Comment: hahaha I mean response.write in my page load of the code, it isnt fired nothing happens no reload zilch i click I get my message box soon as I click ok(confirm) nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because `__doPostBack` is not defined. It's not defined because you didn't put any control on your page that is a an `IPostBackEventHandler`, like `LinkButton` is.

In order to `Page.IsPostBack` to be true, you have to either:

- Re-archtecture your application so that you implement a control that implements `IPostBackEventHandler` and, of course, put it on your page
- You put a dummy `IPostBackEventHandler` on your page. One that doesn't do anything. Like a `LinkButton`.

Either way ASP.NET will define the `__doPostBack` function at client side and your code will finally postback

Comment: woooooHOOOOO it all works fine now! i even get my response! 27! woop which is the div id of the comment i clicked GENIOUS thing is the linkbutton why is it different? why does it hold the IPostback eventhandler? have no clue what that really is and why does java connect to it

Comment: It's because ASP.NET archtecture will search for controls that implement IPostBackEventHandler during life cycle to determine whether or not to declare __doPostBack